# 'corrupt input packet in stream 1' error in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video clip that's 55 minutes and 09 seconds long and I am trying to execute the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb output.ts
```

But then, I get the following error:

```
corrupt input packet in stream 1
```

How do I fix this? What does the error mean?
Here's the full output from FFMPEG:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'myvideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2020-03-31T10:12:07.000000Z
  Duration: 00:55:08.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5134 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-31T10:12:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5016 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-31T10:12:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
Output #0, mpegts, to 'output.ts':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 5016 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-31T10:12:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-03-31T10:12:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 498 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size= 16640kB time=00:00:20.88 bitrate=6527.2/
frame= 793 fps=731 q=-1.0 size= 25856kB time=00:00:32.68 bitrate=6481.1kbits/
frame= 1229 fps=770 q=-1.0 size= 40192kB time=00:00:50.13 bitrate=6567.7kbits/
frame= 1522 fps=726 q=-1.0 size= 48640kB time=00:01:01.84 bitrate=6443.0kbits/
frame= 1932 fps=704 q=-1.0 size= 60160kB time=00:01:18.24 bitrate=6298.2kbits/
frame= 2397 fps=739 q=-1.0 size= 73728kB time=00:01:36.85 bitrate=6236.1kbits/
frame= 2674 fps=714 q=-1.0 size= 81664kB time=00:01:47.92 bitrate=6198.7kbits/
frame= 3068 fps=714 q=-1.0 size= 93696kB time=00:02:03.68 bitrate=6205.5kbits/
frame= 3459 fps=720 q=-1.0 size= 104960kB time=00:02:19.32 bitrate=6171.3kbits/
frame= 3741 fps=705 q=-1.0 size= 114176kB time=00:02:30.61 bitrate=6210.2kbits/
frame= 4178 fps=697 q=-1.0 size= 127232kB time=00:02:48.08 bitrate=6201.0kbits/
frame= 4574 fps=704 q=-1.0 size= 139776kB time=00:03:03.93 bitrate=6225.3kbits/
frame= 4811 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 146944kB time=00:03:13.40 bitrate=6224.0kbits/
frame= 5255 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 160256kB time=00:03:31.17 bitrate=6216.7kbits/
frame= 5606 fps=689 q=-1.0 size= 171520kB time=00:03:45.21 bitrate=6238.9kbits/
frame= 5901 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 180480kB time=00:03:57.01 bitrate=6238.0kbits/
frame= 6360 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 193792kB time=00:04:15.38 bitrate=6216.4kbits/
frame= 6610 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 200960kB time=00:04:25.36 bitrate=6203.8kbits/
frame= 7065 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 214272kB time=00:04:43.54 bitrate=6190.7kbits/
frame= 7295 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 220928kB time=00:04:52.77 bitrate=6181.6kbits/
frame= 7701 fps=687 q=-1.0 size= 232960kB time=00:05:09.01 bitrate=6175.8kbits/
frame= 8048 fps=687 q=-1.0 size= 242944kB time=00:05:22.90 bitrate=6163.5kbits/
frame= 8362 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 251392kB time=00:05:35.44 bitrate=6139.3kbits/
frame= 8823 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 263424kB time=00:05:53.89 bitrate=6097.7kbits/
frame= 9054 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 270336kB time=00:06:03.13 bitrate=6098.5kbits/
frame= 9459 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 281856kB time=00:06:19.32 bitrate=6087.0kbits/
frame= 9753 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 291072kB time=00:06:31.08 bitrate=6097.1kbits/
frame=10040 fps=678 q=-1.0 size= 299264kB time=00:06:42.58 bitrate=6089.6kbits/
frame=10525 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 312576kB time=00:07:01.97 bitrate=6068.2kbits/
frame=10791 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 320000kB time=00:07:12.61 bitrate=6059.5kbits/
frame=10963 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 324608kB time=00:07:19.48 bitrate=6050.7kbits/
frame=11098 fps=659 q=-1.0 size= 328448kB time=00:07:24.88 bitrate=6048.0kbits/
frame=11631 fps=670 q=-1.0 size= 343296kB time=00:07:46.21 bitrate=6032.1kbits/
frame=11965 fps=670 q=-1.0 size= 352512kB time=00:07:59.59 bitrate=6021.3kbits/
frame=12224 fps=666 q=-1.0 size= 360448kB time=00:08:09.94 bitrate=6026.8kbits/
frame=12545 fps=665 q=-1.0 size= 369408kB time=00:08:22.76 bitrate=6019.1kbits/
frame=12969 fps=666 q=-1.0 size= 381696kB time=00:08:39.72 bitrate=6016.4kbits/
frame=13378 fps=666 q=-1.0 size= 393216kB time=00:08:56.08 bitrate=6008.8kbits/
frame=13749 fps=664 q=-1.0 size= 404480kB time=00:09:10.93 bitrate=6014.4kbits/
frame=14195 fps=665 q=-1.0 size= 417024kB time=00:09:28.76 bitrate=6006.4kbits/
frame=14654 fps=668 q=-1.0 size= 429056kB time=00:09:47.13 bitrate=5986.4kbits/
frame=15044 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 441856kB time=00:10:02.72 bitrate=6005.5kbits/
frame=15416 fps=668 q=-1.0 size= 453888kB time=00:10:17.62 bitrate=6020.3kbits/
frame=15776 fps=668 q=-1.0 size= 465408kB time=00:10:32.02 bitrate=6032.4kbits/
frame=16156 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 477184kB time=00:10:47.20 bitrate=6039.9kbits/
frame=16547 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 489728kB time=00:11:02.84 bitrate=6052.5kbits/
frame=16935 fps=668 q=-1.0 size= 502272kB time=00:11:18.37 bitrate=6065.4kbits/
frame=17306 fps=668 q=-1.0 size= 514304kB time=00:11:33.20 bitrate=6077.8kbits/
frame=17796 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 525568kB time=00:11:52.80 bitrate=6040.1kbits/
frame=18336 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 536832kB time=00:12:14.42 bitrate=5988.0kbits/
frame=18764 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 549376kB time=00:12:31.52 bitrate=5988.4kbits/
frame=19214 fps=678 q=-1.0 size= 561664kB time=00:12:49.53 bitrate=5979.1kbits/
frame=19651 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 574208kB time=00:13:07.00 bitrate=5977.0kbits/
frame=20071 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 585984kB time=00:13:23.81 bitrate=5972.0kbits/
frame=20448 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 596992kB time=00:13:38.90 bitrate=5972.1kbits/
frame=20833 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 608256kB time=00:13:54.28 bitrate=5972.6kbits/
frame=21252 fps=678 q=-1.0 size= 620032kB time=00:14:11.04 bitrate=5968.3kbits/
frame=21703 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 632832kB time=00:14:29.09 bitrate=5965.0kbits/
frame=22093 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 644096kB time=00:14:44.69 bitrate=5964.1kbits/
frame=22496 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 655360kB time=00:15:00.82 bitrate=5959.8kbits/
frame=22902 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 667136kB time=00:15:17.05 bitrate=5959.5kbits/
frame=23322 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 679168kB time=00:15:33.84 bitrate=5957.9kbits/
frame=23712 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 690432kB time=00:15:49.46 bitrate=5957.1kbits/
frame=24136 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 703232kB time=00:16:06.42 bitrate=5961.0kbits/
frame=24556 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 715008kB time=00:16:23.20 bitrate=5957.4kbits/
frame=24950 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 726016kB time=00:16:38.97 bitrate=5953.6kbits/
frame=25374 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 738816kB time=00:16:55.93 bitrate=5957.5kbits/
frame=25795 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 750592kB time=00:17:12.76 bitrate=5953.8kbits/
frame=26244 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 763392kB time=00:17:30.72 bitrate=5951.8kbits/
frame=26664 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 775680kB time=00:17:47.54 bitrate=5952.3kbits/
frame=27114 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 788224kB time=00:18:05.52 bitrate=5948.4kbits/
frame=27554 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 800000kB time=00:18:23.12 bitrate=5940.9kbits/
frame=28015 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 812032kB time=00:18:41.57 bitrate=5931.1kbits/
frame=28487 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 824576kB time=00:19:00.45 bitrate=5923.0kbits/
frame=28820 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 833536kB time=00:19:13.76 bitrate=5918.3kbits/
frame=29149 fps=687 q=-1.0 size= 842240kB time=00:19:26.93 bitrate=5912.6kbits/
frame=29461 fps=687 q=-1.0 size= 850944kB time=00:19:39.41 bitrate=5910.5kbits/
frame=29834 fps=686 q=-1.0 size= 862720kB time=00:19:54.32 bitrate=5917.5kbits/
frame=30254 fps=686 q=-1.0 size= 875264kB time=00:20:11.13 bitrate=5920.2kbits/
frame=30644 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 887040kB time=00:20:26.72 bitrate=5923.6kbits/
frame=31034 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 898560kB time=00:20:42.32 bitrate=5925.2kbits/
frame=31454 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 910848kB time=00:20:59.13 bitrate=5926.0kbits/
frame=31667 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 917760kB time=00:21:07.64 bitrate=5930.9kbits/
frame=32111 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 930304kB time=00:21:25.41 bitrate=5928.9kbits/
frame=32426 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 939520kB time=00:21:38.00 bitrate=5929.5kbits/
frame=32711 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 947456kB time=00:21:49.41 bitrate=5927.5kbits/
frame=32987 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 956928kB time=00:22:00.44 bitrate=5936.7kbits/
frame=33284 fps=678 q=-1.0 size= 967424kB time=00:22:12.32 bitrate=5948.3kbits/
frame=33644 fps=677 q=-1.0 size= 979712kB time=00:22:26.72 bitrate=5959.5kbits/
frame=34058 fps=677 q=-1.0 size= 991744kB time=00:22:43.28 bitrate=5959.4kbits/
frame=34454 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 1004288kB time=00:22:59.13 bitrate=5965.4kbits/
frame=34870 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 1016576kB time=00:23:15.77 bitrate=5966.4kbits/
frame=35291 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 1029376kB time=00:23:32.60 bitrate=5969.6kbits/
frame=35654 fps=675 q=-1.0 size= 1041920kB time=00:23:47.13 bitrate=5980.8kbits/
frame=36073 fps=675 q=-1.0 size= 1053952kB time=00:24:03.88 bitrate=5979.7kbits/
frame=36493 fps=675 q=-1.0 size= 1066752kB time=00:24:20.69 bitrate=5982.7kbits/
frame=36884 fps=674 q=-1.0 size= 1079040kB time=00:24:36.32 bitrate=5987.5kbits/
frame=37304 fps=674 q=-1.0 size= 1091584kB time=00:24:53.14 bitrate=5988.9kbits/
frame=37650 fps=673 q=-1.0 size= 1103104kB time=00:25:06.96 bitrate=5996.6kbits/
frame=38084 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1116672kB time=00:25:24.32 bitrate=6001.2kbits/
frame=38504 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1129216kB time=00:25:41.14 bitrate=6002.4kbits/
frame=38924 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1141760kB time=00:25:57.92 bitrate=6003.7kbits/
frame=39499 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 1152256kB time=00:26:20.92 bitrate=5970.7kbits/
frame=40021 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 1160448kB time=00:26:41.81 bitrate=5934.8kbits/
frame=40510 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1168640kB time=00:27:01.37 bitrate=5904.6kbits/
frame=40877 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1177344kB time=00:27:16.05 bitrate=5895.2kbits/
frame=41364 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 1189120kB time=00:27:35.52 bitrate=5884.1kbits/
frame=41751 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 1200128kB time=00:27:51.01 bitrate=5883.5kbits/
frame=42175 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1211904kB time=00:28:07.97 bitrate=5881.5kbits/
frame=42682 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 1223936kB time=00:28:28.24 bitrate=5869.5kbits/
frame=43036 fps=685 q=-1.0 size= 1232640kB time=00:28:42.40 bitrate=5862.6kbits/
frame=43294 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 1241600kB time=00:28:52.73 bitrate=5870.0kbits/
frame=43611 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 1251328kB time=00:29:05.40 bitrate=5873.1kbits/
frame=43952 fps=683 q=-1.0 size= 1262336kB time=00:29:19.06 bitrate=5878.7kbits/
frame=44342 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1274368kB time=00:29:34.65 bitrate=5882.6kbits/
frame=44702 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1285632kB time=00:29:49.05 bitrate=5886.9kbits/
frame=45114 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1298176kB time=00:30:05.52 bitrate=5890.1kbits/
frame=45508 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1310464kB time=00:30:21.28 bitrate=5894.4kbits/
frame=45872 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1322752kB time=00:30:35.86 bitrate=5902.4kbits/
frame=46292 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 1335552kB time=00:30:52.64 bitrate=5905.5kbits/
frame=46682 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 1347328kB time=00:31:08.24 bitrate=5907.9kbits/
frame=47101 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 1359360kB time=00:31:25.01 bitrate=5907.6kbits/
frame=47601 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 1370880kB time=00:31:45.00 bitrate=5895.1kbits/
frame=48224 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 1380608kB time=00:32:09.94 bitrate=5860.3kbits/
frame=48715 fps=686 q=-1.0 size= 1388800kB time=00:32:29.56 bitrate=5835.7kbits/
frame=49143 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 1395456kB time=00:32:46.69 bitrate=5812.6kbits/
frame=49735 fps=691 q=-1.0 size= 1406208kB time=00:33:10.37 bitrate=5787.7kbits/
frame=50149 fps=692 q=-1.0 size= 1414400kB time=00:33:26.93 bitrate=5773.4kbits/
frame=50546 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1422080kB time=00:33:42.80 bitrate=5759.2kbits/
frame=50880 fps=692 q=-1.0 size= 1429248kB time=00:33:56.18 bitrate=5750.2kbits/
frame=51388 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1439488kB time=00:34:16.48 bitrate=5734.2kbits/
frame=51742 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1448192kB time=00:34:30.65 bitrate=5729.4kbits/
frame=52106 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1456640kB time=00:34:45.20 bitrate=5722.6kbits/
frame=52482 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1465856kB time=00:35:00.24 bitrate=5717.6kbits/
frame=52931 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1476352kB time=00:35:18.20 bitrate=5709.7kbits/
frame=53110 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1480960kB time=00:35:25.37 bitrate=5708.2kbits/
frame=53584 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1494528kB time=00:35:44.34 bitrate=5709.5kbits/
frame=53892 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1503744kB time=00:35:56.64 bitrate=5711.9kbits/
frame=54222 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1512960kB time=00:36:09.85 bitrate=5712.0kbits/
frame=54532 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1522432kB time=00:36:22.24 bitrate=5715.1kbits/
frame=54851 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1531648kB time=00:36:35.00 bitrate=5716.3kbits/
frame=55288 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1543680kB time=00:36:52.50 bitrate=5715.6kbits/
frame=55621 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1552896kB time=00:37:05.81 bitrate=5715.4kbits/
frame=55959 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1562112kB time=00:37:19.33 bitrate=5714.6kbits/
frame=56300 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1571584kB time=00:37:32.96 bitrate=5714.4kbits/
frame=56662 fps=693 q=-1.0 size= 1580288kB time=00:37:47.43 bitrate=5709.4kbits/
frame=57178 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1591552kB time=00:38:08.08 bitrate=5698.2kbits/
frame=57658 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1602048kB time=00:38:27.28 bitrate=5688.1kbits/
frame=58108 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1611520kB time=00:38:45.28 bitrate=5677.4kbits/
frame=58659 fps=698 q=-1.0 size= 1623296kB time=00:39:07.32 bitrate=5665.2kbits/
frame=58901 fps=696 q=-1.0 size= 1631744kB time=00:39:17.01 bitrate=5671.3kbits/
frame=59173 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1639424kB time=00:39:27.89 bitrate=5671.8kbits/
frame=59447 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1647872kB time=00:39:38.85 bitrate=5674.7kbits/
frame=59874 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1659392kB time=00:39:55.92 bitrate=5673.7kbits/
frame=60214 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1668608kB time=00:40:09.53 bitrate=5673.0kbits/
frame=60523 fps=695 q=-1.0 size= 1677056kB time=00:40:21.88 bitrate=5672.6kbits/
frame=60816 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1684992kB time=00:40:33.62 bitrate=5672.0kbits/
frame=61171 fps=694 q=-1.0 size= 1694208kB time=00:40:47.80 bitrate=5670.0kbits/
frame=61296 fps=692 q=-1.0 size= 1698304kB time=00:40:52.82 bitrate=5672.0kbits/
frame=61626 fps=690 q=-1.0 size= 1707008kB time=00:41:06.00 bitrate=5670.6kbits/
frame=62015 fps=690 q=-1.0 size= 1719040kB time=00:41:21.57 bitrate=5674.8kbits/
frame=62393 fps=690 q=-1.0 size= 1729792kB time=00:41:36.68 bitrate=5675.7kbits/
frame=62525 fps=688 q=-1.0 size= 1734144kB time=00:41:41.97 bitrate=5678.0kbits/
frame=62737 fps=686 q=-1.0 size= 1740288kB time=00:41:50.44 bitrate=5678.9kbits/
frame=63143 fps=686 q=-1.0 size= 1752576kB time=00:42:06.69 bitrate=5682.2kbits/
frame=63312 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 1757696kB time=00:42:13.46 bitrate=5683.5kbits/
frame=63601 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 1765632kB time=00:42:25.00 bitrate=5683.3kbits/
frame=63940 fps=684 q=-1.0 size= 1776128kB time=00:42:38.56 bitrate=5686.8kbits/
frame=64116 fps=682 q=-1.0 size= 1781248kB time=00:42:45.60 bitrate=5687.5kbits/
frame=64364 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1788416kB time=00:42:55.52 bitrate=5688.4kbits/
frame=64725 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1798912kB time=00:43:09.97 bitrate=5689.9kbits/
frame=64994 fps=680 q=-1.0 size= 1806848kB time=00:43:20.72 bitrate=5691.4kbits/
frame=65435 fps=681 q=-1.0 size= 1819648kB time=00:43:38.36 bitrate=5693.1kbits/
frame=65585 fps=679 q=-1.0 size= 1823232kB time=00:43:44.36 bitrate=5691.3kbits/
frame=65633 fps=676 q=-1.0 size= 1824768kB time=00:43:46.28 bitrate=5691.9kbits/
frame=66047 fps=674 q=-1.0 size= 1835776kB time=00:44:02.85 bitrate=5690.3kbits/
frame=66195 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1840640kB time=00:44:08.76 bitrate=5692.7kbits/
frame=66527 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 1849088kB time=00:44:22.05 bitrate=5690.2kbits/
frame=66945 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1860096kB time=00:44:38.76 bitrate=5688.4kbits/
frame=67350 fps=672 q=-1.0 size= 1869056kB time=00:44:54.97 bitrate=5681.4kbits/
frame=67610 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 1875968kB time=00:45:05.36 bitrate=5680.5kbits/
frame=67845 fps=670 q=-1.0 size= 1881600kB time=00:45:14.77 bitrate=5677.8kbits/
frame=68349 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 1893376kB time=00:45:34.95 bitrate=5671.2kbits/
frame=68673 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 1901312kB time=00:45:47.88 bitrate=5668.2kbits/
frame=69149 fps=673 q=-1.0 size= 1911808kB time=00:46:06.93 bitrate=5660.3kbits/
frame=69267 fps=670 q=-1.0 size= 1914624kB time=00:46:11.64 bitrate=5658.9kbits/
frame=69699 fps=671 q=-1.0 size= 1924608kB time=00:46:28.92 bitrate=5653.2kbits/
frame=69894 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 1931520kB time=00:46:36.73 bitrate=5657.7kbits/
frame=70283 fps=670 q=-1.0 size= 1942016kB time=00:46:52.28 bitrate=5657.0kbits/
frame=70536 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 1948928kB time=00:47:02.42 bitrate=5656.7kbits/
frame=70870 fps=669 q=-1.0 size= 1957888kB time=00:47:15.77 bitrate=5656.0kbits/
frame=70915 fps=666 q=-1.0 size= 1959168kB time=00:47:17.56 bitrate=5656.1kbits/
frame=71187 fps=665 q=-1.0 size= 1967104kB time=00:47:28.44 bitrate=5657.3kbits/
frame=71543 fps=664 q=-1.0 size= 1975808kB time=00:47:42.69 bitrate=5654.0kbits/
frame=72012 fps=665 q=-1.0 size= 1987328kB time=00:48:01.44 bitrate=5650.0kbits/
frame=72205 fps=664 q=-1.0 size= 1992192kB time=00:48:09.17 bitrate=5648.7kbits/
frame=72652 fps=665 q=-1.0 size= 2003968kB time=00:48:27.04 bitrate=5647.1kbits/
frame=72884 fps=664 q=-1.0 size= 2010368kB time=00:48:36.32 bitrate=5647.1kbits/
frame=73051 fps=663 q=-1.0 size= 2015488kB time=00:48:43.00 bitrate=5648.6kbits/
frame=73194 fps=661 q=-1.0 size= 2019328kB time=00:48:48.72 bitrate=5648.3kbits/
frame=73586 fps=660 q=-1.0 size= 2029824kB time=00:49:04.40 bitrate=5647.4kbits/
frame=73764 fps=658 q=-1.0 size= 2034688kB time=00:49:11.52 bitrate=5647.3kbits/
frame=73981 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2040576kB time=00:49:20.21 bitrate=5647.0kbits/
frame=74310 fps=656 q=-1.0 size= 2049280kB time=00:49:33.37 bitrate=5646.0kbits/
frame=74775 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2062336kB time=00:49:51.97 bitrate=5646.7kbits/
frame=75041 fps=656 q=-1.0 size= 2069504kB time=00:50:02.60 bitrate=5646.2kbits/
frame=75501 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2081536kB time=00:50:21.01 bitrate=5644.4kbits/
frame=75757 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2087936kB time=00:50:31.27 bitrate=5642.6kbits/
frame=76182 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2099456kB time=00:50:48.25 bitrate=5642.2kbits/
frame=76474 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2106624kB time=00:50:59.94 bitrate=5639.8kbits/
frame=76820 fps=656 q=-1.0 size= 2117888kB time=00:51:13.76 bitrate=5644.5kbits/
frame=77330 fps=658 q=-1.0 size= 2129920kB time=00:51:34.18 bitrate=5639.1kbits/
frame=77571 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2135296kB time=00:51:43.80 bitrate=5635.8kbits/
frame=78003 fps=658 q=-1.0 size= 2148864kB time=00:52:01.10 bitrate=5640.1kbits/
frame=78242 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2156544kB time=00:52:10.64 bitrate=5643.1kbits/
frame=78686 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2169600kB time=00:52:28.41 bitrate=5645.2kbits/
frame=79152 fps=658 q=-1.0 size= 2183168kB time=00:52:47.06 bitrate=5647.0kbits/
frame=79375 fps=657 q=-1.0 size= 2189824kB time=00:52:55.95 bitrate=5648.4kbits/
frame=79866 fps=659 q=-1.0 size= 2202368kB time=00:53:15.60 bitrate=5645.8kbits/
frame=80190 fps=659 q=-1.0 size= 2208768kB time=00:53:28.57 bitrate=5639.3kbits/
frame=80722 fps=660 q=-1.0 size= 2219264kB time=00:53:49.84 bitrate=5628.8kbits/
frame=81334 fps=662 q=-1.0 size= 2230016kB time=00:54:14.33 bitrate=5613.5kbits/
frame=81762 fps=663 q=-1.0 size= 2235648kB time=00:54:31.46 bitrate=5598.2kbits/

myvideo.mp4: corrupt input packet in stream 1
Error applying bitstream filters to an output packet for stream #0:0.

frame=82367 fps=665 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2247388kB time=00:54:55.70 bitrate=5586.2kbits/

s speed=26.6x
video:2019848kB audio:52552kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.443726%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can tell ffmpeg to drop corrupt packets i.e.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +discardcorrupt -i myvideo.mp4 -c copy output.ts
```

With version 4, required bitstream filters are automatically applied.